# Observe opened windows with SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook

I'm trying to observe opening and closing windows with a global Windows hook. Therefore I'm trying to pass callback functions to the DLL containing my hook procedure. However, the hook procedure itself never gets called.

```
/** Handle to this DLL */
HINSTANCE dllModule = 0;
/** Hook procedure */
HHOOK windowHook = 0;
/** Callbacks are called when a new window is opened, or closed. */
HWND_CALLBACK windowOpenCallback = 0;
HWND_CALLBACK windowCloseCallback = 0;

WINDOWHOOK_API int WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    if(reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        dllModule = hInstance;
        std::cout << "Process attached." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        std::cout << "Process detached." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (reason == DLL_THREAD_ATTACH)
    {
    }
    else if (reason == DLL_THREAD_DETACH)
    {
    }
    return 1;
}

WINDOWHOOK_API bool setWindowHook(HWND_CALLBACK openCallback, HWND_CALLBACK closeCallback)
{
    if(windowHook != 0 || windowOpenCallback != 0 || windowCloseCallback != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    windowOpenCallback = openCallback;
    windowCloseCallback = closeCallback;
    windowHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, (HOOKPROC)hookCallback, dllModule, 0);

    return windowHook != 0;
}

WINDOWHOOK_API bool releaseWindowHook()
{
    bool result = windowHook != 0 && UnhookWindowsHookEx(windowHook) != 0;

    windowHook = 0;
    windowOpenCallback = 0;
    windowCloseCallback = 0;

    return result;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK hookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "Hook callback" << std::endl;

    return CallNextHookEx(windowHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

From my main program, I load the library and call the setWindowHook procedure. I then simply start an infinite loop and wait for the hook to be called, but although the setWindowHook doesn't fail, the hook procedure is never called. I don't understand why.

I tried setting a WH_KEYBOARD hook. With that, the hook procedure got called on keypresses, but only if they were inside the console window of my program.

I'm compiling this to 32bit on a 64bit machine. However, shouldn't it at least work for all my 32bit applications?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your hook is probably getting called however it will be called on a thread belonging to the process where it has been injected. It will try to output to `std::cout` in the context of the other process and for most windows process this will fail as they do not have an attached console.  Use another method for monitoring your hook which does not involve writing to the console.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. However, now I am facing another one. The idea of passing a callback to be called whenever a window opens does not really work. While I could make the function ptr shared across all processes that have the DLL loaded, the processes couldn't call it, cause they live in a different address space. How could I have them communicate with my program? I could send window messages, but these are not guaranteed to be handled, are they?

Comment: Posting messages back to your main windows works (read about WM_COPYDATA). Shared memory will work (with suitable locking) . Sockets can work but you have to careful with the handles.

Comment: Thanks alot. The message approach actually worked. However I think I have read somewhere, that cross process messages are not guaranteed to be handled. Is that correct, or can I be sure that all messages I send actually reach their target?

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` is specifically designed to cross process boundaries. That being said, do be aware that window messages are subject to *User Interface Privilege Isolation* (UIPI), so you should call [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202.aspx) to allow your receiving HWND to receive `WM_COPYDATA` (or whatever your chosen window message is) from any process of any integrity level.

Comment: Alright, thanks. However I'm using [PostThreadMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx) and send the message to a thread without a HWND. I'll do some more testing and see if it catches all the messages. Btw, should I answer my own question now?

Comment: A global hook is the wrong tool. To monitor window creation and destruction, use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx). Added bonus: This approach doesn't require any IPC, and you no longer have to wait for `PostThreadMessage` to fail (see [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a deeper look at that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I got it to work with the DLL and [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), however the [SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) solution works even better and you don't need a DLL for that.
The only problem was, that the WINEVENTHOOK has no LPVOID pointer attribute that we can pass a class instance to. So if you're looking for an OO-approach and are  struggling with that, [this codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14843/Finding-module-name-from-the-window-handle) might help.

Also make sure, that whatever thread you set the hook from, has a message loop, or you won't receive any events.

```
while (!stopped)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        // you don't have to do anything here
    }
}
```